# how to add page name in url of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

In my wordpress site I have two types of pages: About Us and News. The About Us page is just a general page that contains some site information whereas page News will contains posts from admin.

So, is it possible to configure wordpress so that:

1. url: `http://localhost/worpress/about-us` will direct to my About Us Page
2. url: `http://localhost/wordpress/news` will direct to my News pages
3. url: `http://localhost/wordpress/news/?p=123` will direct to specific news posted under News Page.

Any links to tutorial will surely help more.

Thanks

Comment: Well, this appears pretty straight forward. What is your question here? The rewriting module has an excellent documentation with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Did my answer not help?

Comment: sorry for late response, actually I have some another priority issue to solve. I will get back to this things. And obviously if this solves my problem then I will mark your answer solved.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about what WordPress refers to as [Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks).

Please see the link above, but in a nutshell...

Requirements:

1. Apache web server with the `mod_rewrite` module installed
2. In WordPress's home directory:

   - The `FollowSymLinks` option enabled
     `FileInfo` directives allowed (e.g. `AllowOverride FileInfo` or
     `AllowOverride All`)
   - An .htaccess file (if this file is missing,
     WordPress will try to create it when you activate "pretty"
     permalinks)
   - If you want WordPress to update the .htaccess file
     automatically, WordPress will need write access to the file.

You'll then want to head to the admin and change your [Permalink settings to point to Post Name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure).